# Different key-sets on two different keyboards

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have 2 keyboards on my laptop - first one is the default that came with the laptop. The second one is a USB keyboard. Unfortunately, the computer detects same keys for both. Is it possible to have Windows (8.1) detect (lets say) small alphabets a-z and numbers 0-9 on one (default) keyboard; and (lets say) capital alphabets A-Z and specialkeys !-* on the second (USB) keyboard?